# Are we supposed to flag community-faq-proposed questions?

Tags: discussion, community-faq

I recently marked the popular question [How should I choose my DNS?](https://superuser.com/questions/387034/how-should-i-choose-my-dns) as `community-faq-proposed`. And [according to the wiki](https://superuser.com/tags/community-faq-proposed/info)

> Community FAQ questions should be clear, concise, and understandable.
>   If a question could make a viable Community FAQ entry, tag it with
>   community-faq-proposed. Once the question has suitable answers which
>   meet these guidelines, it can be **tagged by a moderator** or user
>   experienced with the subject as community-faq.

(Emphisis mine)

So I assumed that it ment that I should flag for moderator since only a moderator can move it from proposed to actual `Community-FAQ` However this is the response that I got

> I propose to make this question a Community FAQ question. It is very
>   general, has good answers, and Max's answer has good a discussion
>   about the potential drawbacks of using a alternative DNS provider. –
>   11 hours ago
>
> **declined** - flags should only be used to make moderators
>   aware of content that requires their intervention

But it does *require their intervention*, that is how a question moves from proposed to accepted. I suggest that if flagging the tag is the improper procedure that the wiki be edited to make the instructions more clear.

Answer (score 5):

I agree the tag entry could be made more clear. There is no actual technological restriction on the tag - anyone can use it, we just restrict it by convention.

If you think a post should be a [community-faq](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-faq), then you could bring it up for discussion in our chat room. If several experienced users seem to agree, then go ahead and retag it.

The actual retagging doesn't need to be done by a moderator. We just ask that there is a community consensus before a question is given this tag.

Comment: Why bring it up in the chat room and not here? I think it'd be easier to assess agreement on Meta (through votes), and I have the feeling we still have to get people to use Meta more :)

Comment: I don't think declaring something community-faq requires so much discussion that it needs a whole meta thread. If a few people think "sure it looks good," that's criteria enough as far as I'm concerned. Marking something community-faq is not A Big Deal, we just don't want to mark _every_ post someone happens to like.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. It's just that I've seen it done before IIRC.